# Powershell Start-Process bugs out when using credentials

Tags: powershell, start-process

So I've set up some credentials to be imported from an encrypted text file, an am trying to use them in conjunction with the 'start process' cmdlet.
I'm new to powershell so cld be missing smoething obvious, but if i type  `Start-Process powershell.exe` it opens a new ps windows as expected, however trying `StartProcess powershell.exe -Credential $cred` doesnt work. I know its not about not having the access rights on the credentials provided, cos I get hit with the error message `Start-Process: This command cannot be run due to the error ; The filename or extension is too long`
This is confusing me as I havent changed the filename / source - all ive done is provided credentials. I've even confirmed that the `$cred` is indeed a credential, and if i type it into the terminal i do indeed get the username and System.Security.SecureString back.

Any Ideas?

Edit: My code looks like this:

```
[string]$pswd= Get-Content 'C:\Users\USER\pswd.txt'
[SecureString]$ss= $pswd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
[string]$un ='USERNAME'
[PSCredential]$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($un, $ss)
Start-Process powershell -Credential $cred
```

And The Password is set like this:

```
[string]$Password='PASSWORD'
[SecureString]$SS = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
[string]$STR = $SS | ConvertFrom-SecureString
$STR | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\USER\pswd.txt'
```

Comment: Just checked starting notepad.exe while passing credentials of a test user into Start-Process and it worked fine. Can you share some code with us?

Comment: I've added that in now, thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue is the way you're saving the secure string to read later. Try this:

```
$pwd = "Password"
$pwds = $pwd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$pwdse = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $pwds
$pwdse | Out-File "C:\Users\User\pswd.txt"
```

Then to read it back in:

```
$pwd = Get-Content "C:\Users\User\pswd.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

From then on, you can create your PSCredential object the same as normal and it should work fine.

Comment: Oh wait I'm an idiot, I added a line in where i recalled the password to check if it the fetching of the content was an issue, and completely forgot I had done that, even when using the code you wrote, I still get a filename is too ling issue. The weirdest part is that the issue is on the line where the start process is called, not on the line where the password is imported

Comment: What is the full line for your Start-Process cmdlet? Can you provide me with the complete error text you're getting from PowerShell, too?

Comment: The start process line is:
_Start-Process powershell -Credential $cred_

Comment: And the error:                   _Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The filename or extension is too long.
At line:5 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand_

Comment: Just out of interest, are you running this in PowerShell itself or via the PowerShell IDE?

Comment: I'm using the ISE (I assume you meant ISE not IDE?)  just because its easier to edit, although the program calls a powershell window, not the ISE. However I was originally using powerhsell itself when I first found the problem, so I dont think it's related

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in PSReadLine, as running:

```
Remove-Module PSReadLine
```

in the parent process fixes up the stdin redirection and allow you to type into console.